# Django Admin: add custom fields to template pages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I'm new to Django so this might be a simple question. I'm trying to build a portfolio site using Django. I'd like to have a homepage, portfolio page, portfolio detail pages, and contact page. There will be about 20 portfolio detail pages - Project A, Project B, Project C. Each project (portfolio detail page) has multiple areas where I can input text that is populated through the Django admin. How do I create custom fields in the admin for each Portfolio Detail page (headline, project name, url, description) and display them in the page template?

I'm confused as do I use the pages section in the Django admin and add custom fields for each page or do I create a custom app with these custom fields? Then let's say Project B needs an extra field for awards. How do I add that custom field for just the Project B page in the Django admin?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you can't add any number of fields to your project by just linking them with foreign keys.

project/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Project(models.model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ProjectField(models.model):
     project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
     fieldname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     value = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
```

With what you are describing, it sounds like you would like to edit the `ProjectField` values in the `Project` admin page.  The way that the admin page handles that normally is with [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

As an example for the models above:

projects/admin.py

```
from projects import models
from django.contrib import admin


class ProjectFieldInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.ProjectField
    extra = 0


class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProjectFieldInline]


admin.site.register(models.Project, ProjectAdmin)
```

I can't say one hundred percent that this will work for what you are asking, but I recomend giving the app above a try and seeing how close it is to what you want.